# I am having trouble understanding why .'split' is 'stopping' at the middle of my string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I am trying to parse a line at each ',' and adding it to a list of strings. When i attempt to print out my list, I only get 'half' of the values of my original string. I have added as much comments to my code as I can to make reading it easier.

```
void test(String p) {


List<String> split = [];

print('this is my p $p'); // this prints out ' this is my p Reps:3-3-3-3,Exercise:benchpress,muscleGroup:chest,Date:Mar14,2022,Weight:120'

// split = p.split(","); i tried double quotations just in case it mattered. it did not
split = p.split(',');

//tried using for each
split.forEach((element) {
  //print(element); //prints out only 'Reps:3-3-3-3' 'Exercise:benchpress' 'muscleGroup:chest'
});

//i tried using at
print(split.elementAt(0)); // prints out Reps:3-3-3-3

print(split.elementAt(1)); // prints out Exercise:benchpress

print(split.elementAt(2)); // prints out muscleGroup:chest

print(split.elementAt(3)); // does not print
print(split.elementAt(4)); // does not print
print(split.elementAt(5)); // does not print

//another attempt using []
print(split[0]);// prints out Reps:3-3-3-3
print(split[1]);// prints out Exercise:benchpress
print(split[2]);// prints out muscleGroup:chest
print(split[3]); // does not print
print(split[4]); // does not print
print(split[5]); // does not print
```

}

(i did not use for loops so i could comment on the same line)
Since my string p=
Reps:3-3-3-3,Exercise:benchpress,muscleGroup:chest,Date:Mar14,2022,Weight:120'
I thought using .split would cause it to become
split[0]='Reps: 3-3-3-3'

split[1]='Exercise:benchpress'

split[2]='muscleGroup:chest'

split[3]='Date:Mar14'

split[4]='2022'

split[5]='Weight:120'

What am I misunderstanding? Thank you very much.

Comment: You code works perfectly in dartpad

Comment: I am using vscode/android emulator. After reading your comment, i tried closing and re-opening vscode. No luck.. not sure what is going on

Comment: Could you try on physical device? Cause i just copied you function to dartpad and used you string.

Comment: Also, could you print the output split to see what it contains cause if nothing was printed, it should have raised and exception.

Comment: I currently do not have a physical android device. I also tried it on dartpad, and the output is what i want. I will keep trying something

Comment: if i do '  print(split);', the output is '[Reps:3-3-3-3, Exercise:benchpress, muscleGroup:chest, Date:Mar14, 2022, Weight:120]
'

Comment: Well at this point I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: haha well thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate it